# Encrypt parameters to JWT(JSON web token) using JS in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, json, encryption

I want to generate JWT using JavaScript on HTML page.

I looked at Online JWT service [Click Here](http://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/tool_jwt.html), but can't get proper idea.

So is there any solution to generate JWT using JavaScript in HTML page.

I've encode and decode method in c# code. but i want to encode parameter from java script and will decode in c# code.

My c# Code look like:

```
 public static string Encode(object payload, byte[] key, JwtHashAlgorithm algorithm)
        {
            var segments = new List<string>();
            var header = new { typ = "JWT", alg = algorithm.ToString() };

            byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonSerializer.Serialize(header));
            byte[] payloadBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonSerializer.Serialize(payload));

            segments.Add(Base64UrlEncode(headerBytes));
            segments.Add(Base64UrlEncode(payloadBytes));

            var stringToSign = string.Join(".", segments.ToArray());

            var bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);

            byte[] signature = HashAlgorithms[algorithm](key, bytesToSign);
            segments.Add(Base64UrlEncode(signature));

            return string.Join(".", segments.ToArray());
        }


        public static string Decode(string token, byte[] key, bool verify = true)
        {
            var parts = token.Split('.');
            var header = parts[0];
            var payload = parts[1];
            byte[] crypto = Base64UrlDecode(parts[2]);

            var headerJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(header));
            var headerData = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(headerJson);
            var payloadJson = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64UrlDecode(payload));

            if (verify)
            {
                var bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(header, ".", payload));
                var keyBytes = key;
                var algorithm = (string)headerData["alg"];

                var signature = HashAlgorithms[GetHashAlgorithm(algorithm)](keyBytes, bytesToSign);
                var decodedCrypto = Convert.ToBase64String(crypto);
                var decodedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

                if (decodedCrypto != decodedSignature)
                {
                    throw new SignatureVerificationException(string.Format("Invalid signature. Expected {0} got {1}", decodedCrypto, decodedSignature));
                }
            }

            return payloadJson;
        }
```

Your answer will appreciable.

Thanks,

Hardik